Trying to use I2S for stereo pair of INMP441 MEMS mics on Raspberry Pi Pico
Following this specification:
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2S.html
I have stored the following script on my RPi Pico:
from machine import I2S
from machine import Pin

sck_pin = Pin(18)  # Bit clock output
ws_pin = Pin(19)   # Word clock output
sd_pin = Pin(20) # Serial data input
audio_in = I2S(2,
               sck=sck_pin, ws=ws_pin, sd=sd_pin,
               mode=I2S.RX,
               bits=32,
               format=I2S.STEREO,
               rate=22050,
               ibuf=20000)
               
samples = bytearray(2048)                                # bytearray to receive audio samples

num_bytes_read = audio_in.readinto(samples)

But it fails:
'ValueError: invalid id'
somewhere in the I2S call.

Found the solution:
The two I2S buses on the RPi Pico are numbered 0 and 1.
So the first parameter of the I2S call should be 0 (not 2 as above).
then it runs correctly.
